# Layouts in public dir in Sinatra (caching files using the same layout)

Tags: ruby, caching, layout, sinatra

I want to put files in public dir, but I want to give them a layout cause many files will have the same layout. Is this possible? I want to do this because I want them to be served fastest, w/o being rendered each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether your host has Varnish Cache installed, and in Sinatra you can just send a 'cache-control' header, and your application server will only be hit once for the request:

```
get '/rendered_page/:which_page' do 
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=300'
  haml :"pages/#{params[:which_page]"
end
```

And then put your pages in 'views/pages' with a .haml extension.

On the first request, Varnish has no record of what should be served, so your application generates the full HTML. Subsequent requests do not reach your app because Varnish sends back what it had from the previous request.

Heroku, for instance, has Varnish available by default: http://docs.heroku.com/http-caching

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Heroku too. 1) How do I cache a page indefinitely and prevent the user (who presses Shift + refresh) from causing a regeneration? 2) The Heroku link you gave says, "[caching] may result in a brief performance hit to the app, particularly serving of static assets, for the first user to hit the site after the changes are in place." How do I prevent that by making sure the new page is in the cache before it is served? I want to address these two issues because they slow performance w/o any benefit to the user, and AFAIK, these issues do not exist for static pages. Thanks!

Comment: 1. You can adjust the 'max-age' to be very large, however every time you redeploy your app the varnish cache is wiped. Shift refresh has no effect with varnish - they still get the cached page. It's server side caching not client side. 2. I really wouldn't worry about it - the saving you make is huge in comparison to this slight slow down. You could write a 'tickle script' that gets run in a git post deploy hook that hits many common pages. Varnish has HUGE benefit for the end user - you get lots more pages / second vs serving the same pages via ruby.

Comment: thanks! It'd be nice if updated pages automatically get written to Varnish so not even the first user to hit the page gets a delay. Anyway, I read [about Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/about) and it looks sweet.

Comment: Can I set Varnish to respond to a POST request with a cached page? I'm asking because Facebook makes it's initial request to an app with a POST request. Facebook also sends a signed_request parameter with this POST request. Is it also possible to process this signed_request parameter with Sinatra and send a cookie back with the cached page? The page will always be the same, but the cookie (and thus the HTTP response header) will be different every time. I.e., the page doesn't have to be built by ERB every time since it will always be the same, but it does use the power of ERB templating & vars

Comment: AFAIK you can't cache post with Varnish. But you could try doing a redirect "/something_static" as the response, which you then send a cache-response on - but I'm not convinced you'd be able to inject that header. And it also depends if Facebook's code follows redirects or not. If you're worried about responsiveness here, you could render the result once and put it into Memcache, then just return the cached result rather than rendering it each time. Take a look at the dalli gem: https://github.com/mperham/dalli and memcache is a free add-on for Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

For very fastest, what you want is to pre-generate the output using the layout and views and save these as static files in the public directory. If you are using Haml as your template language, for example, it has a command-line version that produces the HTML output.

Alternatively:

- Use the [Sinatra-cache](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-cache) library.
- Read these [posts on the sinatra discussion group](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sinatra+caching&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=+site%3agroups.google.com+sinatra+caching&sa=X&ei=feMgTbKpKKGBnAe004CcDg&ved=0CDIQrQIwAw&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229) regarding caching